# howto to create mysql database from fabric dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql, fabric

Is it possible to create mysql database from fabric dynamically.

This seems like it gets stuck at the password prompt

```
run('mysql -u %s -p %s -h %s  ' % (env.mysqluser, env.mysqlpassword, env.mysqlhost), pty=True)
run('CREATE DATABASE %s; ' % (dataname), pty=True)
run('exit', pty=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try instead

```
run('echo "CREATE DATABASE %s;"|mysql --batch --user=%s --password=%s --host=%s' % (dataname, env.mysqluser, env.mysqlpassword, env.mysqlhost), pty=True)
```

Comment: Won't that save the password in the shell history log?

Comment: @Stavros Considering these are open tools which are freely available, you should probably go to the trouble of checking yourself rather than asking me.

Comment: Considering that my checking and not seeing it there will not prove that it doesn't get stored anywhere, the better solution is to ask you (as you might know more about this) rather than assume I checked every place such a critical security hole might manifest in, not to mention that not everyone who sees this might be inclined to go to the trouble of checking for themselves. Thanks for answering, though (and, for the record, I didn't see the password or the command in the shell log).

Comment: Even though the password is not stored in the shell history log, this does expose the password through such simple tools as "ps" (if you manage to time your attack correctly). So the security aware are well advised to steer away from this solution.

Comment: In fact, this method is mentioned at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-security-user.html as "convenient, but insecure", together with alternatives that are better

Answer (score 21):

There's a better way of doing this using mysqladmin:

```
run('mysqladmin -u %s -p%s create %s' % (user, password, dbname))
```

Comment: Won't that save the password in the shell history log?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following one liner via command line

```
mysql -uroot -prootpassword -e "CREATE DATABASE dbname";
```

key is the -e switch.
if you like to have bash script with variables in db/user/pass and run it as ./myscript then

```
#!/bin/bash
```

> ```
> DB="mydb"
> USER="user1"
> PASS="pass_bla"
>
> mysql -uroot -prootpassword -e "CREATE DATABASE $DB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
> mysql -uroot -prootpassword -e "CREATE USER $USER@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASS'";
> mysql -uroot -prootpassword -e "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON $DB.* TO '$USER'@'127.0.0.1'";
> ```