# django: how to bootstrap/create a database with fabric on the remote server, using django db settings

Tags: python, mysql, django

I would like to add the "create table" command to my fabric bootstrap code (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886780/howto-to-create-mysql-database-from-fabric-dynamically)). For simplicity and error proneness, I want to use my db credentials that are stored in the relevant django settings file. As far as I know, there is no "createdb" command for manage.py, so this must be done manually.

Comment: you can use django connection_created signal to execute any query just after the connection is setup. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.backends.signals.connection_created

Comment: I guess I cannot use this, as there will be no connection, if there's no db yet?

Comment: and, with fabric, I'm in a shell context...

Comment: I guess the cleanest way to do this would be writing a `createdb` management command...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the hard part is getting the settings. the sql command is quite similar to the one from @marco-frattallone .

1) import contrib.django from fabric:

```
from fabric.contrib import django as fab_django
```

2) set env in a setup method, so we can access django settings later in different tasks, if needed.

```
fab_django.settings_module(env['project_conf'])
from django.conf import settings
# access them, 'cause they are lazy load (I guess?! doesnt work otherwise!)
settings.DATABASES
env.settings = settings
```

3) the main "create_database" fabric task:

```
@task
def create_database():
    # this will fail straight if the database already exists.
    run("echo \"CREATE DATABASE {dbname} CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;"
        "\" | mysql -u {dbuser} --password={dbpassword}".format(
        dbuser=env.settings.DATABASES["default"]["USER"],
        dbpassword=env.settings.DATABASES["default"]["PASSWORD"],
        dbname=env.settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"],
    )
)
```

taken from my own, complete fabfile: https://github.com/benzkji/django-layout/blob/master/fabfile.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use syncdb command for adding new models or can install [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) app to handle schema and data migrations.

If you want to use fabric I use this task:

```
def create_database(dbuser, dbname, host, password, dbmanager, dbpassword, dbhost):
    run(("echo \"CREATE DATABASE %s CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
        " GRANT USAGE ON %s.* to %s@'%s' IDENTIFIED BY '%s';"
        " GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON %s.* TO %s@'%s';"
        " FLUSH PRIVILEGES;\" | mysql -u %s  -h %s --password=%s")
        %(dbname, dbname, dbuser, host, password, dbname, dbuser, host, dbmanager, dbhost, dbpassword))

    pass
```

Comment: I know that ;-). It's about automating the creation of the database, i.e. the "create database .." part.

Comment: thx. any way getting the db credentials from django settings? I would prefer not to store them in another file (fabfile)...otherwise, it is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886780/howto-to-create-mysql-database-from-fabric-dynamically

Comment: I use to set db credentials as environment variables

Comment: access django settings is possible with fabric. http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/django.html so accessing these settings, and then run a sql query like the above, would be the solution. will keep you posted when having succeded.

Answer (score -3):

You need to execute a command like this: `mysql> GRANT ALL ON menagerie.* TO 'your_mysql_name' @ 'your_cl` where `your_mysql_name` is the MySQL user name assigned to you and `your_client_host` is the host from which you connect to the
server.

Download from this link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/propertyshelf.fabfile.plone/propertyshelf.fabfile.plone-0.1.tar.gz

Comment: dont get this. fabric connects via ssh to my server, so no need for such things?